# How to convert the first letter of all words of several columns of a csv file to uppercase while making the rest of the letters lowercase?

Tags: bash, awk, sed

**Bash 4.4.0
Ubuntu 16.04**

I have several columns in a CSV file that are all capital letters and some are lowercase. Some columns have only one word while others may have 50 words. At this time, I convert column by column with 2 commands and it is quite taxing on the server when the file has 50k lines.

Example:

```
#-- Place the header line in a temp file
head -n 1 "$tmp_input1" > "$tmp_input3"
#-- Remove the header line in orginal file
tail -n +2 "$tmp_input1" > "$tmp_input1-temp" && mv "$tmp_input1-temp" "$tmp_input1"
#-- Change the words in the 11th column to lower case then change the first leter to upper case
awk -F"," 'BEGIN{OFS=","} {$11 = tolower($11); print}' "$tmp_input4" > "$tmp_input5"
sed -i "s/\b\(.\)/\u\1/g" "$tmp_input5"
#-- Change the words in the 12th column to lower case then change the first leter to upper case
awk -F"," 'BEGIN{OFS=","} {$12 = tolower($12); print}' "$tmp_input5" > "$tmp_input6"
sed -i "s/\b\(.\)/\u\1/g" "$tmp_input6"
#-- Change the words in the 13th column to lower case then change the first leter to upper case
awk -F"," 'BEGIN{OFS=","} {$13 = tolower($13); print}' "$tmp_input6" > "$tmp_input7"
sed -i "s/\b\(.\)/\u\1/g" "$tmp_input7"
cat "$tmp_input7" >> "$tmp_input3"
```

Is it possible to do multiple columns in a single command?

Here is an example of the csv file:

```
"dealer_id","vin","conditon","stocknumber","make","model","year","broken","trim","bodystyle","color","interiorcolor","interiorfabric","engine","enginedisplacement","engineaspiration","engineText","transmission","drivetrain","mpgcity","mpghighway","mileage","cylinders","fuelconditon","optiontext","description","titlestatus","warranty","price","specialprice","window_sticker_price","mirrorhangerprice","images","ModelCode","PackageCodes"
"JOHNVANC04A","2C4RC1N73JR290946","N","JR290946","Chrysler","Pacifica","2018","","Hybrid Limited FWD","Mini-van, Passenger","Brilliant BLACK Crystal PEARL Coat","","..LEATHER SEATS..","V6 Cylinder Engine","3.6L","","","AUTOMATIC","FWD","0","0","553","6","H","..1-SPEED A/T..,..AUTO-OFF HEADLIGHTS..,..BACK-UP CAMERA..,..COOLED DRIVER SEAT..,..CRUISE CONTROL..","======KEY FEATURES INCLUDE: . LEATHER SEATS. THIRD ROW SEAT. QUAD BUCKET SEATS. REAR AIR. HEATED DRIVER SEAT.","","0","41680","","48830","","http://i.autoupktech.com/c640/9c40231cbcfa4ef89425d108e4e3a410.jpg",http://i.autoupnktech.com/c640/9c40231cbcfa4ef89425d108e4e3a410.jpg","RUES53","AAX,AT2,DFQ,EH3,GWM,WPU"
```

Here's a snippet of the above columns refined

```
Column 11 should be - "Brilliant Black Crystal Pearl Coat"
Column 13 should be - "Leather Seats"
Column 16 should be - "Automatic"
Column 23 should be - "1-Speed A/T,Auto-Off Headlights,Back-up Camera"
Column 24 should be - "Key Features Include: Leather Seats,Third Row Seat"
```

Keep in mind, the double-quotes surrounding the columns can't be stripped. I only need to convert certain columns and not the entire file. Here's an example of the columns 11, 13, 16, 23 and 24 converted.

```
"Brilliant Black Crystal Pearl Coat","Leather Seats","Automatic","1-Speed A/T,Auto-Off Headlights,Back-up Camera","Key Features Include: Leather Seats,Third Row Seat"
```

Comment: Please post example input file and expected output you want to have. I think with gnu sed you can. 1. turn everything lower case. 2. then `sed 's/\W./\U&/g'`

Comment: Hey, you need this: 
"This is one field","This is another field"
or this
"This Is One Field","This Is Another Field"
?????

Comment: I know it is off-topic but that would be a breeze with Python's [```str.title()```](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#text-sequence-type-str).

Comment: i.e.: ```'just,a,LONG,LIST of SOme,RaNdOm wORDS'.title()```, results in ```'Just,A,Long,List Of Some,Random Words'```.

Comment: ok... let me improve it to handle the multiple words

Comment: Plz, check my new answer, it should fit your needs

Comment: I just posted an alternative answer using an one liner in sed.

Comment: Everyone's answer breaks column 23. I still need to keep the columns separated by commas and enclosed with double-quotes.

Comment: So I guess you should really give it a try on Python 3 and it's [```csv module```](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html). I can't see an easier way.

Comment: The result in column 23 shows `Auto-Off` and `Back-up`. It looks puzzling to me. Which is your desired treatment after a dash?

Comment: The word after the dash can be treated as a new word for uniformity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another alternative (off-topic here, I know) in Python 3:

```
import csv
from pathlib import Path

infile = Path('infile.csv')
outfile = Path('outfile.csv')

titled_cols = [10, 12, 15, 22, 23]
titled_data = []

with infile.open() as fin, outfile.open('w', newline='') as fout:
    for row in csv.reader(fin, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL):
        for i,col in enumerate(row):
            if i in titled_cols:
                col = col.title()
        titled_data.append(row)    
    csv.writer(fout, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL).writerows(titled_data)
```

Just define the columns you want to be title cased on `titled_cols` (columns have zero based indexes) and it will do what you want.

I guess `infile` and `outfile` are self-explanatory and `outfile` will contain the modified version of your original file.

I hope it helps.

Comment: This stops at empty columns. Example: If I want to convert columns 8, 10, 11 but column 9 is empty column 10, 11 will not be converted. So close mate.

Comment: Damn! Give me a more complete sample of your ```csv``` file and I will try to fix that. I just put that out of my mind and based on what you showed us.

Comment: In fact, I think the fix is trivial: I guess we just need to pass ```quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL``` to ```csv.reader()``` as well. Not tested though. Could you give it a try and tell us the results? If that works, I will edit the answer with that modification.

Comment: Alright. Just tested it here and now the code deals with empty columns as well. Give it try, please.

Comment: You really went out of your way here. Testing now.

Comment: I received so much knowledge and information over the last few days on this thread. It's pretty amazing how everyone gets together and helps everyone out. Now your script was right on. I always variable full paths so I called your python script from my shell script. I crunched 5 k lines in under 2 seconds. Tilting a cold one in your direction. Much appreciated.

Comment: @CuriousSam, I'm glad to know it worked. Welcome to Python world, mate. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Just to add another option, here is a one liner using just [`sed`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sed):

```
sed -i -e 's/.*/\L&/' -e 's/[a-z]*/\u&/g' filename
```

And here is a proof of concept:

```
$ cat testfile 
jUSt,a,LONG,list of SOME,RAnDoM WoRDs
ANother LIne
OneMore,LiNe
$ sed -e 's/.*/\L&/' -e 's/[a-z]*/\u&/g' testfile 
Just,A,Long,List Of Some,Random Words
Another Line
Onemore,Line
$
```

If you want to convert just the headers of the `CSV` file (first line), just replace `s` with `1s` on both search patterns.

You can find an excellent article explaining the magic here: [sed – Convert to Title Case](https://pseudoscripter.wordpress.com/2013/12/02/sed-title-case/).

Comment: I think the conversion is wanted for the complete file. The example code does have `head -1`, but the snippet of the columns refined shows data from the second line. Replace `1s` with `s` if you agree. I upvoted your good answer and honest link regardless.

Comment: @WalterA just did that and thanks for the upvote. I was waiting for the OP to say what he really wanted. :-)

Comment: There's an image column there so I can't change the entire file. Only certain columns. Columns still need to be enclosed by double-quotes and separated by commas. Apologies if my OP was not clear.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a user-defined function and apply it to the columns you need to modify.

```
awk -F, 'function toproper(s) { return toupper(substr(s, 1, 1)) tolower(substr(s, 2, length(s))) } {printf("%s,%s,%s,%s\n", toproper($1), toproper($2), toproper($3), toproper($4));}'
```

Input:

```
FOO,BAR,BAZ,ETC
```

Output:

```
Foo,Bar,Baz,Etc
```

Answer (score 1):

This version uses [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html) to do the job:

This is the command (change `file` to your filename)

```
awk  -F"," 'BEGIN{OFS=","}{ for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) { $i=toupper(substr($i,1,1))""tolower(substr($i,2,length($i)))}print $0}' file | awk -F" "  'BEGIN{OFS=" "} { for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) { $i=toupper(substr($i,1,1))""substr($i,2,length($i))}print $0}'
```

The test:

```
cat file
pepe is cool,ASDASD ASDAS,and no podpoiaops
awk  -F"," 'BEGIN{OFS=","}{ for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) { $i=toupper(substr($i,1,1))""tolower(substr($i,2,length($i)))}print $0}' file | awk -F" "  'BEGIN{OFS=" "} { for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) { $i=toupper(substr($i,1,1))""substr($i,2,length($i))}print $0}'
Pepe Is Cool,Asdasd Asdas,And No Podpoiaops
```

Explanation

- `BEGIN{OFS=","}` tells awk how  to outuput the line.
- The `for` statement uses NF, the built in internal variable for the 
  number of fields for each line
- The substr divide and change the first letter of the field, and it's assigned to its line value again
- All row is printed `print $0`
- Finally, the second `awk` divides the lines created on the first example, but this time dividing with spaces as separator. This way, It detects all different words on the file, and changes every first Character of them.

Hope it helps

Comment: As said in the OP, some columns may be multiple words. Since you are using ```,``` as the field separator, will it handle words separated with spaces in the the same column?

Comment: It will change the FIRST letter of the field. I was exactly asking this. It does not matter for spaces for changing first letter. If we need to change all words, is easy too

Comment: Just as I suspected, hence the question. :-) Let's see what the author really wants.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the fields of the csv file are not quoted by double quotes,
meaning that we can simply split a record on commas and whitespaces, how
about a `Perl` solution:

```
perl -pe 's/(^|(?<=[,\s]))([^,\s])([^,\s]*)((?=[,\s])|$)/\U$2\L$3/g' input.csv
```

input.csv:

```
Bash,4.4.0,Ubuntu,16.04
I have several columns in a CSV file,that, are, all capital letters
and  some are lowercase.
Some columns have only,one,word,while others may have 50 words.
```

output:

```
Bash,4.4.0,Ubuntu,16.04
I Have Several Columns In A Csv File,That, Are, All Capital Letters
And  Some Are Lowercase.
Some Columns Have Only,One,Word,While Others May Have 50 Words.
```

Comment: I'm not sure but I'm under the impression that the OP wants to convert just the first line of each file (I'm guessing that by that head -1 in their commands).

Comment: @accdias thank you for your comment. I understand your point although the OP's requirements are still ambiguous. I will be able to update my answer if the requirements will be clear.

Comment: Yes, they are. My example above shows all columns double-quoted. Apologies if that wasn't clear.